# Windows Store universal app - ListView oddity

Tags: windows, listview, store, universal

I am developing an universal app and using a `ListView` to display more than 50000 entries. I am using the following method to load the data:

1. In the assets folder there's a simple utf-8 txt file with all the items (headwords of a dictionary in alphabetical order just to be precise).
2. I load the file into an `IList` with `ReadLinesAsync`:

   ```
   IList<string> lista1 = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(listafile1);
   ```
3. Finally I set the ItemsSource of the ListView to this IList:

   ```
   listView1.ItemsSource = lista1;
   ```

It seems to be fast and work fine but at the end of the list the items are disappearing after scrolling. I experience this on phones and pc and even in the emulator too. [I made a video of it to be more clear.](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=8FB033BDA1E13D3A&id=8FB033BDA1E13D3A%21316&v=3)

I already created the same app for android and ios and didn't experience this type of error.

I would appreciate any help

István

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a VirtualizingStackPanel to ListView in xaml:

```
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
```